# How To Get OAuth 2.0 Access Token From Postman Using C#

Tags: c#, php, api, oauth-2.0

Im trying to make an app that allows you to upload files to dropbox.
I created upload system etc. on this app and created postman page to get Token.

[My Postman Auth2.0 Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk20L.png)

When i try to get access token by clicking "Get New Access Token" its works like a charm!
But i dont have any idea to get this token in c# i tried to create php post function but its return [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rddaV.png)

my code is this i think im taking wrong url or something please help;

```
var client = new RestClient("https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<clientid>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth.pstmn.io%2Fv1%2Fbrowser-callback");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <author. code>");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        request.AddHeader("Cookie", "locale=en; t=<t>; __Host-js_csrf=<auto-code>; gvc=<gvc>");
        var body = @"\";
        request.AddParameter("text/plain", body,  ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        print(response.Content);
```

I get this code by taking the link and clicked code and converted to c# on postman website `https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<clientid>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth.pstmn.io%2Fv1%2Fbrowser-callback`

Comment: You can not make this request from your code. Getting the access token requires user interaction - you need to send the user to this URL _in their browser_.

Comment: Okey than is it possible to  get the OAuth 2.0 in a cURL? I only pressed one button and one button only postman does the rest of it and gaves me the token

Comment: No, getting a user token in OAuth always requires user interaction. https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide I don't know what exactly you did in Postman or what happens there, I can only assume that you granted your app access at an earlier point already - in which case the auth dialog will redirect straight back to your app URL, which I guess is happening here. Postman _does_ "visit" that URL as if it was a browser, but since the redirect back to the app URL happens right away, you probably did not _notice_ this step happening.

Comment: I see.. i was thinking to try using Resharper library, send the php code the dropbox and get the token by myself.